# Visual Studio 2013: Build for Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp

I got a program made in Visual Studio 2013 (C#). I want to build it to XP. If I take the exe in the Debug directory and I run it on XP, I have an error "Is not a valid win32 application". What I have to do to build it for XP?

Comment: Don't use XP with .NET, you can lower the .NET version. But .NET programs don't work properly on XP. (From experience)

Comment: @KugBuBu - .NET works just fine on XP! How do you think .NET has been running for the past decade+? There are lots of reasons this error might occur (x86 vs x64 and .NET installed / versions etc). But to say "Don't use XP" is stretching it a little!

Comment: Which version of .NET does the app target?

Comment: @Belogix I tried .NET 2.0 on XP. I tried to load images and do some GDI+ and it did a lot of bugs. (On Windows 7, it did fine) I needed to tune it to XP to make it work. I said it because it's was really a pain.

Comment: Is your app build for x64 system and your XP OS x86?

Comment: My XP is x64 but I don't know where to look to see if I'm building for x86!

Comment: I set it to build on x86. Ready! But still the same message...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution: You got to right-click in the solution name on the Solution Explorer and go to Properties. In there, you can not only change the platform (x64 or x86) but the .NET Framework. I downgraded to .Net Framework 4 and worked perfectly!